# DBus Introspection incomplete/wrong

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus

I'm trying to work with Bluetooth LE on a RPI4, and am following the [Bluetooth® Technology for Linux Developers](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-for-linux/) official guide. The python code works fine, but I have to do it in c++, and as of now, I'm blocking at the Advertising step.

I then tried to Intospect the service created by the python programme to compare to what I'm doing in c++, but the introspection result is strange : [Intospection in d-feet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3FLi.png)

I don't understand why the org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1 interface is there instead of the org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1 interface. Have I broken dbus ? or are invisible interfaces just a thing ?

## Edit

I compared the code for the `server_advertising.py` example of the Bluetooth® Technology for Linux Developers guide, and for the [`example-advertisement`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement) of the bluez git, and found out that most likely, in the first one, they are implementing the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1`interface while naming it `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1`...

That would be why I get the same result when introspecting the two, whith only the interface name changing.

As for why I can't see the Properties, from what I now understand, they appear (in both examples) to not have properly registered them, and just overrode the GetAll method to return whatever value they have in their programs. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Thanks to you I now understand the result i got, but I am sad to learn that the introspection won't be usefull...

Comment: You have not broken the DBus, but you lack some understanding of the underlying interfaces. Please read the corresponding BlueZ documentation:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt

Comment: @Risto, I read the file you linked, but as far as I understand, the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1` interface should only appear under /org/bluez/hci0 in the `org.bluez`service (it does), and I should see a `org.bluez.LEAdvertement1` interface under /org/bluez/ldsg/advertisement0, (I was even able to call the GetAll method on it), but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

BlueZ uses a technique where an interface (`org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1`) is defined for the developer to create the advertisement and publish it to D-Bus.

The location of that created interface implementation is given to BlueZ using the `RegisterAdvertisement` command on the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1` interface.

This is why the interfaces that need to be implemented are documented as:

```
Object path:    freely definable
```

Because the relevant Register* command will be used to tell BlueZ the object path of the interface that has been implemented.

To state this a different way, BlueZ provides a blueprint for D-Bus services that it needs to do certain things. e.g. advertising or an agent. The documented interface has no implementation. This is created for the specific instance (e.g. what is to be to advertised). BlueZ is told where to find this interface implementation with the specific Register* command.

Using the example at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement.
I can see that I have started the service but I am not able to introspect it because there is no introspection information given.

To advertise:

```
 $ python3 example-advertisement
```

In another window I can see a new service is published but there is no access to introspect on the service:

```
$ busctl list | grep python
:1.862                              23113 python3         pi               :1.862        session-1820.scope        1820    -
$ busctl introspect :1.862 /org/bluez/example/advertisement0
Failed to introspect object /org/bluez/example/advertisement0 of service :1.862: Access denied
```

The `GetAll` method is implemented so I can call that (with sudo):

```
$ sudo busctl call :1.862 /org/bluez/example/advertisement0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties  GetAll s org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1
a{sv} 7 "Type" s "peripheral" "ServiceUUIDs" as 2 "180D" "180F" "ManufacturerData" a{qv} 1 65535 ay 4 0 1 2 3 "ServiceData" a{sv} 1 "9999" ay 5 0 1 2 3 4 "LocalName" s "TestAdvertisement" "Includes" as 1 "tx-power" "Data" a{yv} 1 38 ay 3 1 1 0
```

Comment: I tried to run the example you linked, in the introspection (I used sudo) I can see as should be the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1` interface under /org/bluez/example/advertisement0, where the example I previously ran had the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1`interface, but I still can't see the list of properties (even though I can call the GetAll method)

Comment: Maybe update your question with output from what you have run. And the code you are using. It will make it easier for people to help you